# "Object does not match target type" when calling SetValue from data obtained by GetValue

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Variables `source` and `target` are two different instances of two different classes.  But they both have an int property called *ID*.

Variables `tProp` and `sProp` are both `PropertyInfo` objects for the ID properties on their respective objects.

`sProp` has value 54, and the IDE Locals windwows shows it as type `obj{int}`

`tProp` is a valid property, not set yet.

I am trying to set target.ID using this code:

```
var sVal = sProp.GetValue(source);
tProp.SetValue(target, sVal);
```

When I hit that line I get "Object does not match target type".

I know that I can fix this by casting `sVal` to `int`, but I'm trying to write generic code here, and thought that at least .NET would be able to determine that the two objects are exactly the same type.  Am I missing something?

Any idea how to solve this, other than checking types and casting?

Comment: Format code with backticks (`\``), not asterisks.

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me. Need full minimal example. My example: https://pastebin.com/raw/ZrxEvaTH Even with generics: https://pastebin.com/raw/DAqULAj3

Comment: It'll be a good idea to show the structure of your two different classes.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo or something, so you are trying to set a value of property which belongs to different object. For example having two classes like this:

```
public class A
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
}

public class B
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
}
```

To reproduce your issue uncomment the line below (sProp doesn't belong to target instance):

```
    var source = new A();
    source.ID = 54;
    var target = new B();

    var sProp = source.GetType().GetProperty("ID");
    var tProp = target.GetType().GetProperty("ID");

    var sVal = sProp.GetValue(source);
    //sProp.SetValue(target, sVal); // will throw Object does not match target type  - sProp doesn't belong to target instance
    tProp.SetValue(target, sVal);
```

I think your statement

> Variables tProp and sProp are both PropertyInfo objects for the ID properties on their respective objects.

is not really true and `tProp` is a property of `source` and `sProp` is a property of `target`, so the runtime error occurs.